# SQL avoid null fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table

[image: SQL Table]

I need to write a query for getting a dataset like below.(Avoid null fields and group by id)
[image]

Please give me direction....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try grouping by the `id`:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(col1) AS col1,
       MAX(col2) AS col2,
       MAX(col3) AS col3,
       MAX(col4) AS col4
FROM test
GROUP BY id
```

The reason this works is that in SQL Server `MAX` ignores `NULL` values, so only the single `VARCHAR` value (e.g. `'ABC'`) will be retained during the grouping operation.

The data in your `test` table appear to be the intermediate step of a pivot query.

Comment: @weeraa please mark as answer if that helped to resolve your issue

Comment: @jacky : Done. :)